# Как правильно выбрать местоимение?

Tags: грамотная-речь, местоимения, местоимение

Москва - очень старый город. Он(а) основан(а) в 1147 году.

В данном предложении нужно писать писать "он" или "она"? "Город" или "Москва"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

И то и другое верно. Она - Москва, он - город.По-моему, всё понятно.

Чаще согласуют рядом стоящие слова: ...город.Он...

Answer (score 2):

Здесь лучше подходит вариант с местоимением ж.р., так как текст про Москву, "город" выступает только в качестве приложения: **Москва ―  очень старый город. Она основана в 1147 году.**

А еще лучше текст исправить (если, конечно, он не учебный для младших школьников), например: **Москва ―  очень старый город, дата ее основания ―  1947 год.**

Answer (score 1):

Да, здесь допустимы оба варианта.
Но я бы здесь отступил от обычного правила (см. Людмила), мне больше по душе вариант первый, "она основана".

Поскольку во всей конструкции название, Москва, занимает более важное место, это подлежащее, а город грамматически принадлежит к именной части составного сказуемого, логически это определяемое и определение (не в грамматических терпинах!), объект и его свойство. Логично будет считать, что в дальнейшем тексте во главу угла ставится Москва, объект, а не её город, свойство этого объекта.